# Computing a sum of fractions using sigma notation

Tags: measure-theory, summation, fractions

Evaluate the following using sigma notation

$$\frac34 + \frac65 + \frac96 + \frac{12}{7} + \frac{15}{8}$$

For the denominator I get $\sum_{i=4}^8 i$ but how about the numerator?

Answer (score 0):

What about

$$\sum_{i=4}^8 \frac{3(i-3)}{i}=3\sum_{i=4}^81-9\sum_{i=4}^8\frac1i$$

Comment: Yes I just figured it out thank u

Comment: @JOJO You are welcome! Bye

Comment: @JOJO: If the answers have helped you then can you accept and/or upvote them to close out the question?